# How to ignore requestAnimationFrame in browsers which don't support it

Tags: javascript, requestanimationframe

Let's say we have a feature / module, that enhances a website. So it is not really necessary and it uses `requestAnimationFrame`, which is [not supported in older browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=requestanimationframe) like IE8/9. I could polyfill `requestAnimationFrame`, but since it's just an enhancement, older browsers should simply ignore it. The code for this module looks more or less like this:

```
;(function( window, document, undefined ) {
    'use strict';

    // Example Module
    // @constructor
    function Module( el, options ) {            
        // ...
    }

    Module.prototype = {
        init: function() {
            // If requestAnimationFrame is not supported, no alert should pop up        
            alert("init");
        },

        method: function() {
            // If requestAnimationFrame is not supported, no alert should pop up
            alert("start");
        }
    };

    window.Module = Module;

})( window, document );
```

I can then create a new instance

```
var instance = new Module(document.getElementById('test'));
```

and "interact" with it

```
instance.init();
instance.method();
```

The problem with this code is that in IE9 an error pops up because IE9 doesn't know "newer" functions like `requestAnimationFrame`. I could just add an `if` statement to

```
if ( window.requestAnimationFrame ) {
    var instance = new Module(document.getElementById('test'));
}
```

and everywhere I use it. It would be much easier to check for `requestAnimationFrame` support once somewhere in the module though. If it isn't supported nothing should happen, older browser should just ignore it. So I tried doing something like

```
// @constructor
function Module( el, options ) {            
    if ( !window.requestAnimationFrame ) {
        return false;
    }
    //...
}
```

But that doesn't prevent older browsers from executing all methods like ".init()" or ".method()" (in this case). Do I really have to put this `if` statement in every single method or is there anything else i can do?

Comment: Did any of these answers work for you?

Comment: @torazaburo Kind of, accepted the most useful to me. Haven't seen the "Additional answer" part in the accepted answer. Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why, when you've already figured out the logic, you choose to implement it as a comment instead. Just replace the comments with code and you're good to go:

```
Module.prototype = {
    init: function() {
        if(typeof requestAnimationFrame === 'undefined') return;        
        alert("init");
    }
};
```

Or you can check `window.requestAnimationFrame` if you prefer.

---

### Additional answer:

#### How to avoid writing many `ifs`

You can encapsulate the `if` statement in your own control structure. As usual in javascript, we use functions to implement new 'syntax':

```
function restricted (f) {
    return function () {
        if(typeof requestAnimationFrame === 'undefined') return;
        return f.apply(this,arguments);
    }
}
```

Now you can define your methods using `restricted(function...` instead of `function`:

```
Module.prototype = {
    init: restricted(function() {
        alert("init");
    }),

    method: restricted(function() {
        alert("start");
    })
};
```

Comment: I just though there's an easier way without having to write the same if statement in each method.

Comment: Sure, this is javascript. The if statement is a control structure. Abstract it out and create your own control structure.

Answer (score 2):

The "polyfill" for RAF is just `setTimeout`. You can find dozens of examples on the web, usually along the lines of

```
window.requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || 
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
    ... || 
    function (callback) {
        setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
    };
```

`setTimeout` does the same thing as RAF, just at a lower resolution and without being so optimized with the engine's rendering process. (RAF also passes a hirez timestamp to the callback.)

Bottom line is there's no reason to worry about RAF not being available and how to fall back if it's not. Just fall back to `setTimeout`.

If you really want to go without it if it's not available, then just put the following line at the top of your module

```
var RAF = window.requestAnimationFrame || ... || function() { };
```

In other words, define it as a null (no-op) function. Then use `RAF` variable inside your methods.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely polyfill it! It will make your code more concise and it is not 'just an enhancement' for browsers, but in this case also an enhancement for the way you can write and structure your own code. You definitely don't want to go that route that you write methods twice with if blocks.
Paul Irish made a great Polyfill for RequestAnimationFrame: http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/

This advice also applies to other browser features, not just RequestAnimationFrame, there are great polyfills for about any feature, e.g. github.com/es-shims/es5-shim

Comment: You are probably right, but writing for IE10+ is much easier and faster than still supporting IE8. It's not just requestAnimationFrame, but all those little workarounds for IE8.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but would this work:?

```
if ( window.requestAnimationFrame ){
     Module.prototype = {
        init: function() {
            // If requestAnimationFrame is not supported, no alert should pop up        
            alert("init");
        },

        method: function() {
            // If requestAnimationFrame is not supported, no alert should pop up
            alert("start");
        }
    };
}
else{
  Module.prototype = {
    init: function() {
    },

    method: function() {
    }
   };
}
```

Then all browsers cal call init and method but methods won't execute anything if it's not suported. So you only have to make the change in the module.

Comment: I think it should work, but then I have to write every method twice.

Comment: @demrks Yeah, you'd have to. Another option is to put `if ( window.requestAnimationFrame )` at the begging of each function, init and method. You've already mentioned this.